# CSS is not applying inside the dynamic table and it was not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, I have created a page with tables with collapse option (i.e Accordion) and also dynamic table within the table it should append to it..But here im trying to apply the class"tableshow" it was applying in HTML but not in the sricpt, Down I wrote Jquery for collapsing. I want the dynamic table onclick it should collapse, Please help me with this.

```
    <style>
        .btn-primary{
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f57f20 !important;
            border-color: #f57f20 !important;
        }

        .inner-block {
            padding: 8em 2em 4em 2em;
            background: #fafafa;
        }
        th{
            padding: 10px;
            color: #f57f20;
        }

        td{
            color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.93); ;
        }

        .panel-default>.panel-heading {
            color: #333;
             background-color: #fafafa;
            border-color: #ddd;
        }

        .text_label{
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .panel-body {
            padding: 1px;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .table  tr.tableshow > td:first-child {
            position: relative;
        }
        .table  tr.tableshow  span.collapseshow{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            position: absolute;
            left: -20px;
            background: #f09d18;
            border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            line-height: 1em;
        }
        .table  tr.tableshow span.collapseshow:before {
            content: "+";
        }
        .table  tr.tableshow.open span.collapseshow
        {
            background: #eee;
            color: #000;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .table  tr.tableshow.open span.collapseshow:before {
            content: "-";
        }

    </style>

    <div class="content-wrapper">


        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row" style="float:right; display: flex; margin-bottom:10px;">

                <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 30px; "><b>Search </b> </p>
                <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
                <input type="text" style="margin-right: 10px;"  class="search-member form-control" />
                <button onclick="export_csv()" class="btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Export to csv
                </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                    <div class="box">


                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body" id="alreadymember">

                            <div id="filtered_append">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                                <tr  style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <th  style="width:5%;" >S.No.</th>  <th   style="width:15%;">Full Name </th> <th  style="width: 10%;"> Role </th> <th  style="width: 15%;"> Email </th> <th  style="width: 12%;">Date Joined </th> <th  style="width: 12%;">Subscribed Date </th>
                                                      <th  style="width: 12%;">Expiry
                                                        Date</th> <th  style="width: 5%;">Edit </th> <th  style="width: 5%;">Delete</th>
                                                </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php foreach ($users['details'] as $key => $value) {

                                    ?>

                                    <tr class="tableshow">

                                                    <td style="width: 5%;" class="text_label"> {{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                                    <td style="width:12%;" class="text_label" style="word-break: break-all;">  {{ $value['sc_fullname'] }}</td>
                                                    <td style="width: 10%;"> <select class="form-control" style="width: fit-content;"
                                                                 data-id="{{ $value['id'] }}"
                                                                 data-role="{{ $value['role'] }}"
                                                                 onchange="change_role(this)"
                                                                 id="admin_role_change">
                                                            <option disabled value="all" selected>Role</option>
                                                            <option <?php if ($value['role'] == 'pioneer') {
                                                                echo 'selected';
                                                            } ?> value="pioneer">Pioneer
                                                            </option>
                                                            <option
                                                                <?php if ($value['role'] == 'pioneer_plus') {
                                                                    echo 'selected';
                                                                } ?> value="pioneer_plus">Pioneer+
                                                            </option>
                                                            <option
                                                                <?php if ($value['role'] == 'pioneer_gold') {
                                                                    echo 'selected';
                                                                } ?> value="pioneer_gold">PioneerG
                                                            </option>
                                                            <option
                                                                <?php if ($value['role'] == 'pioneer_platinum') {
                                                                    echo 'selected';
                                                                } ?> value="pioneer_platinum">PioneerP
                                                            </option>
                                                            <option <?php if ($value['role'] == 'regular') {
                                                                echo 'selected';
                                                            } ?> value="regular">Regular
                                                            </option>
                                                            <option <?php if ($value['role'] == 'team') {
                                                                echo 'selected';
                                                            } ?> value="team">Team
                                                            </option>

                                                        </select></td>
                                                    <td style="width:16%;">{{ $value['sc_email'] }}</td>
                                                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{ date('jS F Y',strtotime($value['created_at'])) }}</td>
                                                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{$value['subscribed_date']}}</td>
                                                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{$value['expiry_date']}}</td>
                                                     <td style="width: 5%;"> <a href="/admin/edit-pioneer-signup/{{ $value['id']  }}">Edit</a></td>
                                                   <td style="width: 5%;"> <a href="#" onclick="delete_user({{ $value['id']  }})">Delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>


                                            <tr style="display: none;">
                                                <td colspan="9">
                                            <table class="table" style="width: 100%; ">

                                                                <tr style="width: 100%;" >
                                                                    <td>Name: {{ $value['sc_fullname'] }}</td>
                                                                    <td>Role: {{ $value['role'] }}</td>

                                                                </tr>

                                                                <tr style="width: 100%;">
                                                                    <td style="width:50%;">Location: {{ $value['sc_location'] }}</td>
                                                                    <td style="width:50%;">Date Joined: {{ date('jS F Y',strtotime($value['created_at'])) }} </td>

                                                                </tr>

                                                                <tr style="width: 100%;">

                                                                    <td style="width:50%;">Looking For:
                                                                        @foreach($value['usermeta'] as $usermeta)
                                                                            {{$usermeta['meta_value']}}
                                                                        @endforeach
                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td style="width:50%;">other Details:
                                                                        @if(($value['user_other_detail']) != null)

                                                                            Hotspot
                                                                            : {{($value['user_other_detail']['hotspot'] == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                                                                            Insurance
                                                                            : {{($value['user_other_detail']['insurance'] == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                                                                            Whatspp
                                                                            : {{($value['user_other_detail']['whatsapp'] == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                                                                            Target Customer
                                                                            : {{$value['user_other_detail']['target_customer']}}
                                                                            startups_name: {{$value['user_other_detail']['startups_name']}}
                                                                            entrepreneur_level: {{$value['user_other_detail']['entrepreneur_level']}}
                                                                            expectation: {{$value['user_other_detail']['expectation']}}
                                                                            Note: {{$value['user_other_detail']['note']}}
                                                                        @endif</td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                            </table>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php } ?>

                                    </tbody>




                                </table>




                </div>
            </div>

                        <div id="pk"></div>
    </div>



</div>
            </div>
        </section>


            <script>

                $('.search-member').keyup(function () {
                    if ($.trim($('.search-member').val())) {
                        $.get('/admin/search-member-pioneer-detail', {info: $('.search-member').val()}, function (data) {
                            var html = '';
                            html = `
                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 100%;">
                                            <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                <tr  style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <th  style="width:5%;" >S.No.</th>
                                                    <th   style="width:15%;">Full Name </th>
                                                    <th  style="width: 10%;"> Role </th>
                                                    <th style="width: 15%;"> Email</th>
                                                    <th style="width: 12%;">Date Joined</th>
                                                    <th style="width: 12%;">Subscribed Date</th>
                                                    <th style="width: 12%;">Expiry Date</th>
                                                      <th  style="width: 5%;">Edit </th>
                                                      <th  style="width: 5%;">Delete</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                     `;
                            var sn = 1;
                            var usermeta = null;
                            var umeta = [];
                            var hotspot = null;
                            var insurance = null;
                            var whatsapp = null;
                            var otherDetail = null;
                            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                usermeta = data[i]['usermeta'];
                                for (var j = 0; j < usermeta.length; j++) {
                                    umeta.push(usermeta[j]['meta_value']);
                                }
                                if (data[i]['user_other_detail'] != null) {
                                    hotspot = data[i]['user_other_detail']['hotspot'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                                    insurance = data[i]['user_other_detail']['insurance'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                                    whatsapp = data[i]['user_other_detail']['whatsapp'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                                    otherDetail = data[i]['user_other_detail'];
                                }

                                html += `<tr>
                          <td>
```

Here I need Accordion using a classname="tableshow" I wrote Jquery Below

```
                               <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse${sn}">
                                         <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom:10px;">
                                         <tr style="width: 100%;" >
                                          <td style="width: 5%;" class="text_label">  ${sn} </td>
                                          <td style="width:12%;" class="text_label" style="word-break: break-all;"> ${data[i]['sc_fullname']}</td>
                                           <td style="width: 5%;">
                                           <select class="form-control" style="width: fit-content;"
                                                                        data-id="${data[i]['id']}"
                                                                        data-role="${data[i]['role']}"
                                                                        onchange="change_role(this)"
                                                                        id="admin_role_change">
                                                                    <option disabled value="all" selected>Role</option>
                                                                    <option   ${(data[i]['role'] == 'pioneer') ? 'selected' : ''} value="pioneer">Pioneer
                                                                    </option>
                                                                    <option ${(data[i]['role'] == 'pioneer_plus') ? 'selected' : ''} value="pioneer_plus">Pioneer Plus
                                                                    </option>
                                                                    <option ${(data[i]['role'] == 'pioneer_gold') ? 'selected' : ''} value="pioneer_gold">Pioneer Gold
                                                                    </option>
                                                                    <option ${(data[i]['role'] == 'pioneer_platinum') ? 'selected' : ''} value="pioneer_platinum">Pioneer Platinum
                                                                    </option>
                                                                    <option ${(data[i]['role'] == 'regular') ? 'selected' : ''} value="regular">regular
                                                                    </option>
                                                                    <option ${(data[i]['role'] == 'team') ? 'selected' : ''} value="team">Team
                                                                    </option>
                                                                    <option ${(data[i]['role'] == 'founder') ? 'selected' : ''} value="founder">Founder
                                                                    </option>

                                                                </select>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width:16%;">
                                                                ${data[i]['sc_email']}
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td style="width:12%;">
                                                                ${data[i]['created_at']}
                                                                    </td>
                                                                <td style="width:12%;">
                                                                ${data[i]['subscribed_date']}
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td style="width:12%;">
                                                                ${data[i]['expiry_date']}
                                                                    </td>
                                             <td style="width:5%;"> <a href="/admin/edit-pioneer-signup/${data[i]['id']}">Edit</a></td>
                                             <td style="width:5%;">   <a href="#" onclick="delete_user(${data[i]['id']})">Delete</a></td>

                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse${sn}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                        <div class="panel-body">

                                        <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <tr style="width: 100%;" >
                                             <td style="width:50%;"> Name:   Name:  ${data[i]['sc_fullname']}</td>
                                             <td style="width:50%;"> Role: ${data[i]['role']}</td>
                                            </tr>
                             <tr style="width: 100%;">
                           <td style="width:50%;">  Email: ${data[i]['sc_email']} </td>
                           <td style="width:50%;">  Mobile: ${data[i]['sc_mobile_no']} </td>
                             </tr>

                             <tr style="width: 100%;">
                           <td style="width:50%;">  Location: ${data[i]['sc_location']}  </td>
                           <td style="width:50%;">
                            Looking For: ${umeta.join()} <br>

                            Hotspot
                            : ${hotspot}<br>
                            Insurance
                            : ${insurance}<br>
                            Whatspp
                            : ${whatsapp}<br>
                            Target Customer
                            : ${(otherDetail != null) ? otherDetail['target_customer'] : ''}<br>
                            startups_name: ${(otherDetail != null) ? otherDetail['startups_name'] : ''}<br>
                            entrepreneur_level: ${ (otherDetail != null) ? otherDetail['entrepreneur_level'] : ''}<br>
                            expectation: ${ (otherDetail != null) ? otherDetail['expectation'] : ''}<br>
                            </td>

                             </tr>
                            </table>

                             </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>


            </tr>`;
                                sn++;
                            }
                            html += `</table>`
                            console.log(data)
                            $('#alreadymember').hide();
                            $("#pk").empty();
                            $("#pk").append(html)
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#alreadymember').show();
                        $("#pk").empty();
                    }
                })
```

Jquery is written Here

```
                $( document ).ready(function() {

                    $(".table tr.tableshow td:first-child").append('<span class="collapseshow"></span>');
                });

                $(document).on("click", ".collapseshow", function() {
                    $(this).parents(".tableshow").next().slideToggle();
                    $(this).parents(".tableshow").toggleClass("open");
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: Your code is nor organized can you use fiddle to show it how is working now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=d7EoUvAov2

Comment: I hope you can uderstand my code following the above fiddle, though everything is coming from PHP, I'm not removing that code. Please help me in this.